# Tab navigation flat design

Tags: visualforce, tab, design

I am trying to change the default design on the salesforce platform with my own flat design. 
I don't know from where i can start. Is it possible ?

Thanks,

Darko

Comment: Please be more specific.  Do you want to change the design of the entire database?  That's not possible.  Do you want to add your own custom objects to a database?  That can be done.  Or are you just trying to change the appearance of an object or objects? (also possible).

Comment: Yes I want to change the entire design. As I saw from below in a way its possible. So I want to know more about it and how its done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are building a VF Page with no Headers and SideBar, the you can perform any CSS Styling.
You can include your CSS Stylesheet using  the  tag.

```
<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.myStyles, 'styles.css')}"/>
```

If you are building a VF Page with Headers and Sidebar, it is still possible to override the Salesforce CSS Styling. But this approach is not recommended.

1. You will be overriding the existing Salesforce CSS.
2. You won't be able to get consistent behavior across the whole platform because your overridden CSS works only in certain pages and there is no way to include your custom CSS in some standard pages.

Is it possible? Yes. But Use caution when architecting these solution.
The below snapshot shows "flattening" of Salesforce Tabs.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A Salesforce database is not like a SQL database.  In a SQL database, you need to create every table you want to work with.  In a Salesforce db, a number of objects are created for you by default.  These are the standard objects. The standard objects come with standard fields, but it is also possible to add custom fields to standard objects. There's a summary of standard objects [here](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/data_model.htm).  The standard objects are often related to other standard objects (eg. one account can have multiple contacts).

When the standard objects don't meet your needs, you can create custom objects.  Custom objects can be related to standard objects or other custom objects.  There is no way to delete the standard objects, although you could probably adjust the security settings to hide them from most users.

There's a video of a training session on extending Salesforce with custom objects [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ehcXKizoNy0).  It goes into considerable detail.